# SQL Dynamic Where clause with multiple tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need some help on this.

I want to get the total cost of every sales:

```
select * from (select salesid, sum(price * qty) as netsales, sum(qty * (select cost from tblproducts)) as totalcost from tblsales_details group by salesid) a inner join tblsales b on b.salesid = a.salesid
```

I have 3 tables, which are tblsales, tblsales_details, tblproducts

I'm using MS Access.

On tblsales column is: salesid

On tblsales_details columns are: salesid, productid, price, qty

On tblproducts columns are: productid, cost

I already have this sql code that works, but I cannot get the total cost

```
sum(qty * (select cost from tblproducts))

a.salesid - netsales - totalcost
```

1 - 1800 - ?

I know its not working but I want to do something like this:

```
sum(qty * (select cost from tblproducts where pid = pid))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you want the following

```
select salesid, 
      sum(d.qty * d.price) as netsales, 
      sum(d.qty * p.cost) as totalcost 
from tblsales_details as d 
join tblproducts as p on d.pid = p.pid
group by salesid
```

Answer (score 0):

Play with the below code and you will see how it all hangs together

```
--try replacing
--SELECT *
--instead of the below select statement and you will see how the SUM part, FROM part  
--and the GROUP BY work together
SELECT
    s.salesid
    ,SUM(d.qty * d.price) as netsales
    ,SUM(d.qty * p.cost) as totalcost 
FROM
tblsales  AS s
    INNER JOIN tblsales_details AS d ON s.salesid = d.salesid
        INNER JOIN tblproducts AS p ON d.productid = p.productid
GROUP BY s.salesid
```